# SWIG -- Using typemap inside of extend

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a c++ class written and I am using SWIG to make a Python version of my class.  I would like to overload the constructor so that it can take in Python lists.  For example:

```
>>> import example
>>> a = example.Array([1,2,3,4])
```

I was attempting to use the typemap feature in swig, but the scope of typemap does not include code in extend

Here is a similar example to what I have...

```
%typemap(in) double[]
{
    if (!PyList_Check($input))
        return NULL;
    int size = PyList_Size($input);
    int i = 0;
    $1 = (double *) malloc((size+1)*sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            PyObject *o = PyList_GetItem($input,i);
            if (PyNumber_Check(o))
                    $1[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
            else
            {
                    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"list must contain numbers");
                    free($1);
                    return NULL;
            }
    }

    $1[i] = 0;
} 

%include "Array.h"    

%extend Array 
{
   Array(double lst[])
   {
        Array *a = new Array();

        ...
        /* do stuff with lst[] */
        ...

        return a;
   }
 }
```

I know the typemap is working correctly (I wrote a small test function that just prints out elements in the double[]).

I attempted putting the typemap inside the extend clause, but that did not solve the problem.

Maybe there is another way to use Python Lists inside of the extend, but I could not find any examples.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a typemap? %extend should be adequate for you to add a constructor that takes a std::list and with std_list.i SWIG will do everything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close: instead of a `double lst[]`, extend with `std::list<double>`:

```
%include "std_list.i" // or std_vector.i

%include "Array.h"    

%extend Array 
{
   Array(const std::list<double>& numbers) {
        Array* arr = new Array;
        ...put numbers list items in "arr", then
        return a; // interpreter will take ownership
   }
}
```

SWIG should automatically convert the Python list to the std::list.

Comment: I was trying to use vector instead of list (it kept saying list is not part of std) and when I type `a = example.Array([1,2.0,3])` it throws an error back saying that is not one of the possible constructors.  Even though it says one of the possible constructors is `example::Array::Array(std::vector< double,std::allocator< double > > const &)`

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? As in the above comment, using neither list nor vector does result in a constructor that is being called.

Comment: @kjyv I'm not set up to dig into this right now unfortunately but based on "kept saying list is not part std" in the comment there were likely other issues like compiler options. I've used the technique before but its been a few  years so maybe now need an extra SWIG option or such, I'm curious to know what's going on there.

Comment: I've tried it a lot today and ran into the same issues. kept saying not part of std can happen because of a missing namespace std block. Nonetheless, with either list or vector, the method is not called and I was unable to find what signature was expected.